# Asp.Net application getting poor performancE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am developing an application which fully works with huge database. In this i am facing a problem that after hosting on server,  if one user execute long query then application hangs for the other users. For sql connection i am using a static class to make only one connection.

Please help and guide me.

If any other information need then please tell me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost impossible to answer a question without specific code and that is broadly worded. However, in this case, you may just have provided enough information.

> For sql connection i am using a static class to make only one connection.

Don't do that.

You are probably forcing all your users to wait until the single connection to the database is available exclusively for that user.

That is like providing a ferry to carry cars across the river that can only hold one car at a time instead of building a bridge.

Allow each user to get their own database connection. The underlying database access layer almost certainly provides connection pooling. There's no reason for you to try that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of security reason you moved your connection string web.conf to class file and that class you made static. Because of static you are facing a problem.

```
public class Connection
{
    private SqlConnection _connectionString;
    public SqlConnection ConnectionString => _connectionString ?? (_connectionString =
                                                new SqlConnection(
                                                    @"Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=dababase name;User ID=sa;Password=password;Max Pool Size=1000;Asynchronous Processing=True;Connect Timeout=30;")
                                            );
}
```